# my mac pro with OS x.11.6 goes to sleep even with the energy saver set to never

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, performance

my desktop mac pro with OS x.11.6 goes to sleep even with the energy saver set to computer sleep never. And keyboard is frozen when computer wakes up, I have to restart.

Answer (score 1):

> my mac pro with OS x.11.6 goes to sleep even with the energy saver set
>   to never

With OS X 11.6 the Caffeinate command in Terminal should work and keep it awake.

Open Terminal in Utility Folder and type `Caffeinate`.

If you want to investigate what is putting it to sleep, open the Console in Utility folder and look at the lines before it goes to sleep (or post it in you post).